# I want to use Autocrat in a Google Sheet macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a macro that calls AutoCrat but when I finish to record the macro and try to execute it says that Autocrat3 is not defined. What it is missing?

```
function Autocrato() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L86').activate();
  AutoCrat3.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use Autocrat or any other Editor add-on from a Google Sheets macro.

The above b/c two the macros are stored in a bounded Apps Script project and the Editor Add-on project in a different project.

#### Reference:

- [Macros: Things you can't do](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros#things_you_cant_do)